# I'm still getting null exception when using the System.Management can't figure out why

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This exception is not happen every time i tried to make it happen now again and only after i clicked the button to start the watcher like 4-5 times in a row one after one ... then closed my program the exception came up.

This is a new class i'm using the management . And it happen only when i close my program after i started the watcher in the new class:

I tried to make try and catch but it didn't stop on any of them.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Management;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MinimizeCapture
{

    class WatchForWindow
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
        private const int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;
        private const int SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2;
        private const int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;

        private static ManagementEventWatcher watcher = null;

        public static void StartWatching()
        {
            try
            {
                WqlEventQuery query = new WqlEventQuery("Select * From __InstanceCreationEvent Within 2 Where TargetInstance Isa 'Win32_Process'");
                watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(query);
                watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(watcher_EventArrived);
                watcher.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                string t = "err " + err.ToString();
            }
        }

        public static void StopWatching()
        {
            try
            {
                if (watcher != null)
                {
                    watcher.Stop();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                string t = "err " + err.ToString();
            }
        }

        private static void watcher_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ManagementBaseObject obj = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"];
                string t = obj["Name"].ToString();
                GetHWND(t);
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                string t = "err " + err.ToString();
            }
        }

        private static void GetHWND(string wName)
        {
            try
            {
                IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow("Chrome_WidgetWin_1 for Chrome", "Untitled - Notepad");
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                string t = "err " + err.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the only place this class that i'm using system.management
Yesterday i was sure the problem is when i'm closing my program i was needed to close also the watcher so i added a method in the class called StopWatching.

This is in form1 how i start the watcher in the class:

```
private void buttonSnap_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WatchForWindow.StartWatching();
        }
```

And this is how i stop it:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            WatchForWindow.StopWatching();
        }
```

This is the exception message:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=System.Management
  StackTrace:
       at System.Management.IWbemServices.CancelAsyncCall_(IWbemObjectSink pSink)
       at System.Management.SinkForEventQuery.Cancel()
       at System.Management.ManagementEventWatcher.Stop()
       at System.Management.ManagementEventWatcher.Finalize()
  InnerException:
```

This is the window i get with the exception message:

[image: Exception Error]

I can't figure out yet what is getting null sometimes ? And why ? And how to solve it.

Comment: You won't be able to easily catch this exception because it is happening in the finalizer of the ManagementEventWatcher. This method is called by the .NET garbage collector after all references to the object have been removed. You can probably avoid this by always ensuring that you have `Stop`ped the watcher before exiting.

Comment: The problem happens because you don't cleanly dispose the watcher. In your StartWatching() just call StopWatching() on the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public static void StartWatching()
    {
        StopWatching(); //add this line
        try
        {
            WqlEventQuery query = new WqlEventQuery("Select * From __InstanceCreationEvent Within 2 Where TargetInstance Isa 'Win32_Process'");
            watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(query);
            watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(watcher_EventArrived);
            watcher.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            string t = "err " + err.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Your problem occurs because you create multiple EventWatchers without cleaning up the old ones. If you make the 1 line change I suggest, you should not have the problem anymore.